# Pass generic prop from interfaces another property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to write an interface that is able to autocomplete nested property based on keys of another property in the interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
Foo?: [key: string]: any
Bar?: (???)
}


const Test: MyInterface = {} 
Test.Foo['Key1'] = "lol";
Test.Bar. //Should be able to drop down autocompletion of keys of Foo
```

Is it possible to do this without converting `Test` to function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) interface. The disadvantage compared to a Generic function here is that the object keys cannot be inferred directly by the object value and you'll have to explicitly pass a generic argument to `MyInterface`.

```
type MyInterface<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  Foo?: T;
  Bar?: {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K];
  };
};

const Test: MyInterface<{Key1: string}> = {Foo: {Key1: "lol"}};

Test.Foo?.Key1;
Test.Bar?.Key1; // Autocompletion suggests "Key1"
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCSA7YEBOAzAhgYwgHgBUoIAPFRAEwGcoAlCbAe1QryuFQEtEBzAGiiZEIAHwioAXigBvAFBQoAMUaMA-AC4oBANzyoAIUyoNMvQoDaAaSjcoAawghG6LQF1NBK690KAvrv9ZWSZEdi0Idk04JBQMHHxpS0cARk12Ll5fcSlpZUZNRJTNACIAG0ZS4t9A2QII4AA6PNUGpJBk3Tr2BsNjVpTtKAB6IagAQQBXYEYmAFswUohgTkZEKCoJnh56mmK25OKgA)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface MyInterface {
    Foo?: { [key: string]: any };
    Bar?: keyof MyInterface['Foo'];
}

const Test: MyInterface = {};
Test.Foo = { Key1: "lol" };
Test.Bar = "Key1"; // Now, you should get autocompletion for keys of Foo
```